# How to conditionally generate html in ASP template

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm a total newbie to this. How do I conditionally wrap this `<Colosseum:PersonLabel...` with `<strong></strong>`

```
<asp:TemplateColumn
    HeaderText="Member"
    ItemStyle-Wrap="false"
    SortExpression="leader_name">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <Colosseum:PersonLabel ID="plPerson" runat="server" 
            PersonGUID='<%# Eval("person_guid") %>' 
            PersonName='<%# Eval("person_name") %>' 
            HasPhoto='<%# Eval("person_blob_id") != DBNull.Value %>'
            Restricted='<%# Eval("restricted") != DBNull.Value && Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("restricted")) %>'
        />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Comment: This should work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16809133/1503509

Comment: Is it like a normal label control? Try `Font-Bold='<%= expression %>'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
Font-Bold='<%# Eval("FeedName").ToString().Contains("Band") %>'
```

It works essentially like the other expressions you have on the label.

```
// true if `person_blob_id` is not null.
HasPhoto='<%# Eval("person_blob_id") != DBNull.Value %>'
```

Comment: This was it. Thank you!