# skip a line/item in asp:repeater

Tags: asp.net, asprepeater, lightgallery

Is there a possible way to skip an item in `asp:repeater`? I have `<ul>` and `<li>`s where I need the ul to be repeated only once. Since it has `id` and ids must be unique.

Here I need to skip repeating the `<ul id="lightgallery">` then continue repeating the `<li>` tags.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptBlogs" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
      <div class="blog-post">
              <div style="display:none;" id="video<%# Eval("ID") %>">
                  <video class="lg-video-object lg-html5" controls preload="none">
                      <source src="<%# !Eval("ArticleTypeValue").ParseString()%>" type="video/mp4">
                          Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
                  </video>
              </div>
              <div class="post-left-img">
                  <ul id="lightgallery"> //this needs to be skipped 
                      <li class="video" style="position: relative;" data-poster="/<%# Eval("ThumbImage").ParseString() %>" data-sub-html="<%# Eval("Description") %>" data-html="#video<%# Eval("ID") %>" >
                          <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                          <img class="img-responsive" src="/<%# Eval("ThumbImage").ParseString() %>" />
                              <div class="demo-gallery-poster">
                                  <img src="/assets/images/play-button.png">
                              </div>
                          </a>
                      </li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I know the common sense fact where the structure should be:

```
<ul>
<asp:repeater>
...
</asp:repeter>
</ul>
```

But that can't be done because of the HTML structure.

**Solved but still open to better ideas.** See below for my solution.

Comment: You don't have to render any markup if you don't want to. You can add conditional logic within your ItemTemplate to inspect the item to determine whether it should be rendered or not. You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16809133/1139830) to see how to do an if statement in your Web Forms markup.

Comment: @mason I thought about that but how would be the condition if I want it to show but only once.

Comment: Sounds like your UL shouldn't be within the repeater at all.

Comment: I know the ideal would be <ul><asp:repeater></asp:repeater></ul> but because of the html structure that is not possible

Comment: You can add a variable to keep track of whether it's been added already or not. But that looks like you're just avoiding the problem instead of properly spending the time to organize your markup.

Comment: @mason I found a solution. Please leave me your thoughts on this

Comment: You could dynamically build up the RepeaterItem and bind it to a placeholder, and have your conditional logic for which items to add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used:

```
<ul id="lightgallery<%# Eval("ID") %>">
```

Instead of:

```
<ul id="lightgallery">
```

Then used jquery starts with selector:

```
$('[id^=lightgallery]')
```

Comment: Then you'll have multiple UL's on your page. If that's intended, then great.

Comment: Thank you. It would be ideal not having them but for now I go with this until I find a better way of doing it

Comment: I showed you how to do an if statement in markup. You can do that with logic like `if (!markupAlreadyAdded) { /* add markup and set markupAlreadyAdded to true */ }`. Still, I think restructuring your HTML would be much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I think a repeater in your repeater might allow you to get what you are looking for you just may have to tweak the data that you are binding.

Check out this answer
[Repeater in Repeater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923137/repeater-in-repeater)

If that doesn't work then you can add an OnDataItemBound (similar to what is shown in the link) to find/remove your control on the server side.